# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1' in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having an error in Xamarin Forms I tried to deserialize the object does anyone know What did I do wrong here?

This is my method

```
private async void GetEmployee()
    {
        var _token = await GetAccessToken();
        //List<D365Employee> Employee = null;
        using (var _clientD365 = new HttpClient())
        {
            var _uri = "domain here";

            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

            var _response = await _clientD365.GetAsync("my endpoint here");

            var Emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(Emp);
        }
    }
```

This is my Model

```
public class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public IList<EmployeeDetails> Value { get; set; }       
}

public class EmployeeDetails
{        
    public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentLegalEntityId { get; set; }
    public string DimensionDisplayValue { get; set; }
    
}
```

This is the JSON I try to parse

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://employee.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#Employees(PersonnelNumber,EmploymentLegalEntityId,DimensionDisplayValue)",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEsNTYzNzE0NDYwMzsxNDg2NTk2NzY0LDU2MzcxNDc2OTM7MSw1NjM3MTQ0NjAzOzEsNTYzNzE0NDYwMzsxLDU2MzcxNDczNzE7MCwwOzAsMDsyNTY0OTEwODksNTYzwJw==\"",

        "PersonnelNumber": "ID111028",
        "EmploymentLegalEntityId": "OOP",
        "DimensionDisplayValue": "----",
        
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: hi @gunr2171 I already edited the post that's the JSON I wanted to parse

Comment: Ahh, Im new to this, what will I do?

Comment: Hi, @judecamp.  It's better to use `async Task` instead of `async void`.

Comment: I tried to use it but Im having issues with HttpContent.ReadAsAsync its looking for reference system Im looking to package manager to install the NuGet but there is no result :(

Comment: "looking for reference" I think you mean that you need to add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` to the top of your file. You should read through the [async programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: I did use the using System.Threading.Tasks; when I tied to return it I got the error
HttpContent does not contain a definition for ReadAsAsync

This is how I do it what did I do wrong here? 

if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new Exception("Error method" + _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                return _response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result;

Answer (score 1):

That JSON is a single object, not a list, so you need to deserialize it as a single object.

```
var Emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Don't use .Result in an async method.  `var Emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't look over that part of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much @gunr2171 it works now! :)

what does this mean "the specified cast is not valid" 
EmployeeD365 = new ObservableCollection<D365Employee>((IEnumerable<D365Employee>)EmpD365);

Comment: `Emp` is a single Employee object, not a list. You need to adjust the next line.

Comment: I will do thank you so much for your help @gunr2171 :)